Why the gnome icon I set does not work for JetBrains IDE
The system I am currently using is Arch Linux. The desktop environment is GNOME.
I installed JetBrains Toolbox through AUR, and then used it to install many IDEs. However, the icons of these IDEs did not change to the icons I set through gnome-tweak. But the IDE I installed directly through AUR did change the icon. But IDEs installed via this method are not pretty, they have an extra bar at the top.
So I was wondering if there is any way to change the icons of those IDEs installed via JetBrains Toolbox.

The icon of the IDE on the left is installed by me using JetBrains Toolbox, and the one on the right is installed through AUR.

The IDE via JetBrains Toolbox

The IDE on this picture was installed via JetBrains Toolbox and it behaves well and has no extra bars on it. While this approach solved the current problem, it introduced new problems and this didn't really solve my problem.


The IDE on this picture was installed via AUR, and it looks weird, with extra bars, and the font changed to the font I set in gnome-tweaks.
As far as I know, its icon can be modified by modifying the .desktop file.
I found these .desktop files in ~/.local/share/applications. But their file names look weird, like this: jetbrains-clion-fada67bb-967d-41a6-902a-9555ae964c1d.desktop
When I opened the program for the first time after making the modification, it did become what I expected, but when I opened the toolbox , the file changed to its original appearance. It seems that the .desktop file is managed by the toolbox program.
I want to know if there is a way to change the native icon to the icon I have in gnome-tweak.

I had the same problem, and this is how I solved. The idea is not to modify jetbrains-webstorm-XXX-XXX-XXX.desktop, but instead create the symbolic link of icon file to the desired file.
First, check the desktop entry file to see which icon file is the app referencing.
cat ~/.local/share/applications/jetbrains-webstorm-XXX-XXX-XXX.desktop | grep Icon

For me, the path is ~/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/webstorm/bin/webstorm.svg.
Remove the icon file.
rm /path/to/referenced/icon

Create the symbolic link to the icon file you want to use
ln -s /path/to/desired/icon /path/to/referenced/icon

If you go to the path where icon was located and use tree | grep webstorm.svg command, you can check that the link is created successfully.
for me: (I'm using numix circle theme)
└── webstorm.svg -> /usr/share/icons/Numix-Circle/48/apps/webstorm.svg

Logout or reboot. Then you will see the icon is changed(even in the toolbox app), and running jetbrains-toolbox won't change the effect.
Result
In the panel
In the toolbox app

Thank you for your answer. I have been so busy recently that I just saw it now. I will try your solution next.
